# What's the easiest way to prevent the substitution of UI components with the system-wide ones?

Tags: android

I designed my application to run on a pretty, nice and clean holo theme (the google default), and when I installed it on my brother's device, I had the unpleasant surprise of finding out that the standard UI components (spinner, progress bars, horizontal progress bars, etc...) were overridden with some kind of factory pre-installed components. Now, those components are good when applied on the system-wide ui, but they suck in my app.

My brother's phone is some kind of Chinese clone of the S4, but I guess the same will happen with other non-Google devices.

The only solution that comes to my mind is to create, for every component I don't want to be overridden, a custom one, copying its xml from the android source code. I don't know exactly how to do that, but seems a lot of trouble compared to what I want to reach.

What's the simplest way to run my app with the holo components in every device?

---

**EDIT in regard to the answers I had**

In my app I have minSdkVersion set to 11. The theme is set in the manifest at the application tag and is "AppTheme", that's configured in this file

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/_AppTheme">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="_AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:progressBarStyleHorizontal">
            @style/Widget.Custom.ProgressBar.Horizontal.Green
        </item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

I will check my brother's device about the play store installed and report here.

I just wanted to update you on the theme since I saw you were talking about Theme.Holo... Maybe there is somthing going on with the AppCompat library?

Comment: Are you sure that your brother's phone has manufacter provied GUI components? I wouldn't say it's very probable. Perhaps it's the question of difference in Android version and some different scalling depending on size screen etc. Could you put here two screenshoots, one from your device and one from your brother's one?

Comment: @user2707175 I will do that in a moment

Comment: sorry, I have to wait for my brother to come home again

Answer (score 1):

> but I guess the same will happen with other non-Google devices.

Not usually.

If the device legitimately has the Play Store on it (i.e., it is not a pirated copy put there by the user or device manufacturer), the `Theme.Holo` set of themes must be left alone. The `Theme.DeviceDefault` set of themes are where device manufacturers can tinker.

And, of course, the holographic widget theme only exists on API Level 11+.

> What's the simplest way to run my app with the holo components in every device?

If your `android:minSdkVersion` is 11 or higher, use a theme that inherits from `Theme.Holo`, and not worry about devices, like your brother's phone, that break that theme.

If your `android:minSdkVersion` is 10 or lower, you are welcome to consider the HoloEverywhere project, though personally I would not. On older devices, the user is going to expect the device's own theme, not a holo theme, and so the user may not recognize things like `EditText` and `Spinner` that look a lot different in a holo theme.

Comment: I use minSdkVersion: 11. I updated the question regarding the theme.

Comment: @domenicop: Sorry, but I have not examined `Theme.AppCompat` to see what it inherits from.

Comment: I checked the Play Store and it seems identical to the one I have on my Nexus 5 with a stock 4.4.2 on it. One thing I found interesting is that even in the Gmail, Play Store, et similia, is used a theme with not default widgets. Can this be a sign that in this particular device the stock `Theme.Holo` has been touched?

Comment: @domenicop: "Can this be a sign that in this particular device the stock Theme.Holo has been touched?" -- possibly. I have no good way of helping you about what things look like when I cannot see them. "I checked the Play Store and it seems identical to the one I have on my Nexus 5 with a stock 4.4.2 on it" -- that does not mean that it is legitimately licensed.